# How to export excel from json data with appropriate row span using SheetJs?

Tags: typescript, xlsx, js-xlsx, sheetjs

I am using `SheetJS js-xlsx` react library to export data to an excel file.

I am trying to export an excel file where there will be a dynamic rowspan for data where necessary. An easy way to do so is to use the `table_to_book()` method where the excel file is generated exactly as it is on the HTML table.

```
var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(document.getElmentById(#idOfTheTable));
```

This does serve my purpose, however, **I want to know if there is any way to export excel files from JSON for such data structure:**

```
const purchaseJsnData= [
  {
    "id": "0",
    "PRNumber": "",
    "TotalAmount": 110,
    "CostCenter": "",
    "Details": [{"ItemDescription": "item1", "Quantity": 1},
                {"ItemDescription": "item2", "Quantity": 3}]
  },
  {
    "id": "10",
    "PRNumber": "111",
    "TotalAmount": 520,
    "CostCenter": "",
    "Details": [{"ItemDescription": "i1", "Quantity": 5},
                {"ItemDescription": "i2", "Quantity": 6}]
  }
]
```

The following line exports excel for plain JSON data where there are no child array values on it.

```
 XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(ws, purchaseJsnData, { skipHeader: false, origin: "A5" });
```

Exporting excel from a direct HTML table allows me to export only the current page data (as there is pagination), I want to export the whole data set which is why searching for a way to export excel from JSON format.